# Clearing/acknowledging of level triggered interrupts

Tags: interrupts, level

I am confused with the clearing/acknowledgement of level triggered interrupts in an SoC. When an interrupt is level triggered should the clearing be done in the interrupt controller or the bus controller (spi controller,gpio controller) or in the peripheral device itself. If I have to clear in the peripheral device itself then I should be connecting a line to from my SoC core to the device, correct? Could somebody also give an example say of SPI device using level triggering?

Comment: Who is the interrupt source? The peripheral device or others?

Comment: It seems a handshake problem, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Asynchronous_circuit&redirect=no#Protocols, search "Four-Phase Handshake"

Comment: The interrupt source is the peripheral device. The diagram would be [Peripheral Device] ->[GPIO Controller] -> [Interrupt Controller] -> [CPU Core]

Comment: Ultimately, you need to clear it at the source of the interrupt (the peripheral device). If the ISR is unable to do so, it could mask the interrupt in the interrupt controller and schedule a thread to finish work on the device before re-enabling the interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

With an edge-triggered interrupt, you can safely exit the ISR right away without any further action because the interrupt will not be triggered until the interrupt pin goes low (or high as the case may be) again.

With a level-triggered interrupt, it is assumed the peripheral causing the interrupt does not reset the level going into the interrupt pin by itself, since it can't know the latency of the ISR). If this interrupt did work this way, and the microcontroller was set up to latch the condition of the signal going high or low, this would just be the same as an edge-triggered interrupt.

So the microcontroller must cause the level to be reset, either within the ISR or in the base level following the ISR.

Depending on the peripheral, there might be two ways to reset the interrupt signal.  One is when the peripheral has a specific pin for this purpose, typically called an interrupt acknowledge.  Pulsing this lead high to low and back (or vice vera) resets the interrupt level.  This is the only method available if the microcontroller has no interface available to manipulate registers inside the peripheral.

The other way to reset a level-triggered interrupt, which is much more common, is to reset (or set) an interrupt acknowledge bit in one of the registers of the device.  This bit would be set by the peripheral itself when the interrupt is generated, and reset by the microcontroller (or vice versa).  Obviously this only makes sense if there are internal registers that can be addressed by the microcontroller, via either I²C, SPI, parallel bus, or other means.  This resetting of a interrupt flag is almost always the way microcontroller acknowledges an interrupt generated by a peripheral located within itself.

The problem with the second approach, is performing an SPI or I²C transfer takes time, and you may not want to spend that much time in your ISR.  So you can disable the interrupt that was triggered and set a flag. As soon as you exit the ISR, and enter some sort of idle condition, then based on the flag being set, you can then perform the I²C or SPI transfer to reset the interrupt flag in the peripheral, and then re-enable the interrupt.  If you are using a multi-tasking operating system of some type, you can generate an event from within the ISR or whatever it needed in you OS to wake up a task to perform this operation.

If you can't disable just the interrupt that was triggered, and you must disable all interrupts, this obviouls will have a much more drastic effect on your system, and it might be preferable just to do the I²C or SPI communication within the ISR and be done with it.

So, if it is so much trouble to handle level-triggered interrupts, why have them in the first place? Because it allows one to have several different peripherals tied to the same interrupt pin, and be able to identify where the interrupt came from.

Say you have only one external interrupt (called Not_Interrupt_In (since I can't use \$\mathsf{\small \overline{\text{Interrupt In}}} \$ in CircuitLab) and two peripherals that can each generate level-triggered interrupts (Not_Interrupt_0 and Not_Interrupt_1).  You tie the interrupt outputs of each of these to the same external interrupt pin through a diode.  It is assumed they are all configured as open-drain, that is, the normal condition if a logic 1, and when an interrupt occurs, the output goes to logic 0.  (If one or both pf the interrupts pins of a peripheral is not open drain, just omit the corresponding resistor.)

[image]

The diodes create an OR gate; it may seem they are backwards but remember we are dealing with negative signals (0 = asserted). I've verified the circuit operation on CircuitLab.

So either interrupt source will cause the external interrupt line on the microcontroller to go to 0, generating an interrupt.  Meanwhile, each interrupt line has its own input to one of the ports on the microcontroller, in this case Port A bits 0 and 1.  So when the interrupt occurs, the ISR can look at port A and determine which peripheral generated the interrupt.

Note this can't be done with edge-triggered interrupts, since it can't be assumed the interrupt line is still asserted by the time the ISR gets control, so a poll would not work.  One could externally feed the edge interrupts into latches, which could be polled, but they would need to be reset by the ISR, and there are some nasty race conditions which have to be avoided.